# Text and Images in TabHost desapear

Tags: android, android-tabhost

So i have made a tabhost in my app (4.2.2) but when i fill the tab indicator with the title of the tabs the images disapear, and when i only put the images path it shows the images but i want to show both. can anyone help me

In this case the images will appear but as y can see the title is not filled
     public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try
    {
        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent;  
        tabHost.clearAllTabs();

        // create an intent for the tab which points at the class file for that tab
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AllProductsActivity.class);

        //give the tab a name and set the icon for the tab
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Pesagem").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_config)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AllContActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contagem").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_config)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AllGuiaActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Guia").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_config)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

if i do this, it only appears the title:

```
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AllGuiaActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Guia").setIndicator("Pesagem", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_config)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

What can i do to have title and an image on the tab

Answer (score 2):

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
tv.setText(text);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsImage);
iv.setImageResource(image);

TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(view)
               .setContent(new Intent(this, activity));
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
```

The layout can just be a LinearLayout with a TextView and an ImageView.

Comment: y are saying to create a layout with an image and textview, then inflate it and storing it to the tabspec that i want. i have 3 tabs ill just have to repeat your example code 3 times

Comment: Correct, do that three times.